# Linux crontab ignores my entry

Tags: linux, cron

Hello there all you awesome people of StackOverflow.

I have a problem with something i have never tried before.
Here is my situation.

I ssh into my dedicated server as root. I run the `crontab -e`, the crontab file is now open, I write in this simple line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/chekifworks.txt
```

then I save it and I get a message that a new crontab job is installed. Everything is great, except that it does absolutely nothing. But guess what! If I change it to this:

```
* * * * * /root/script.sh
```

And the contents of /root/script.sh are simply `touch /tmp/testing.txt`
It still does nothing.

Output of `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/checkifworks.txt
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /etc/webmin/status/monitor.pl
@reboot /etc/init.d/shout
```

Please, mighty gods of SO, help me out on this one, I will gladly provide any information you may need if you need it.

UPDATE: I did a `chmod a+x /root/scrip.sh` still no good.

Comment: Are you sure that `cron` is running, and that you are allowed to use it? BTW, running a process every minute is perhaps too much...

Comment: Hello good sir! How can I check if CRON is running? And I'm not planning to run a command every minute, I'm doing it this way right now just for testing purposes.

Comment: Use `ps auxw` to get a list of all the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually a good thing to use full path to commands in crontab. You should use the following.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/chekifworks.txt
```

The environment in which `cron` runs has a very limited `PATH` variable.

It does not help to use a script (check for it being executable, btw), as the environment is transferred from `cron` to the script, and still very limited.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've changed it as you said, but still nothing happens.

Comment: @Janisimo Basic check: Do you have write permissions to /tmp? Have you tried `/usr/bin/touch /tmp/chekifworks.txt` on the command line?

Comment: That was the fist thing I did, works just fine. Note: I'm doing everything as root because I SSH'ed into the server as root. Don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Then check that `cron` is running: `ps -ef | grep cron`.

Comment: That was it! The CRON process doesn't start automatically on my server for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Check if cron log enable in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (depends on distro).

There must be a stanza `cron.* /var/log/cron.log` (depends on distro).

Add (or uncomment) it and restart syslog `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` if not.

Add to cron this entry `1 * * * * root /usr/bin/touch /tmp/chekifworks.txt`.

Check for errors in `/var/log/cron.log`

Or you can add `>/tmp/my_cron.log 2>&1` to cron entry and check for errors `/tmp/my_cron.log` after a minute (or two to be sure) if you don't want to edit `rsyslog.conf`.